# sapui5 How to keep Horizontal scroll bar in sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have created a `sap.m.Table` with 15 columns, How can I create a Horizontal scroll bar for that particular Table, I Tried with 
[Scroll Container](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ScrollContainer/preview) . But it did not work. Can someone help me to provide Horizontal Scroll bar for `sap.m.Table`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Give width to each table columns

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by specifying *width* property to each table columns

```
<Table> 
    <columns>              
        <Column>
            <Text text="documentNumber"/>
        </Column>
        <Column width="60px">
            <Text text="col_Pos1"/>
        </Column>    
        <Column width="60px">
            <Text text="col_Pos2"/>
        </Column>     
        ......     
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>                 
              <Text text="documentNumber"/>
              <Text text="col_Pos1"/>
              <Text text="col_Pos2"/>
            .....                   
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Comment: actually im able to do that using ScrollContainer only....i just given width for table..then it is worked..thank you for your prompt response

Answer (score 0):

I just given `width` for Table in Scroll Container.. Then im able to fix my issue..

```
<ScrollContainer  width="100%" horizontal="true" vertical="true" focusable="true">
<Table width="100rem"> 
    <columns>              
        <Column>
            <Text text="documentNumber"/>
        </Column>
        <Column width="60px">
            <Text text="col_Pos1"/>
        </Column>    
        <Column width="60px">
            <Text text="col_Pos2"/>
        </Column>     
        ......     
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>                 
              <Text text="documentNumber"/>
              <Text text="col_Pos1"/>
              <Text text="col_Pos2"/>
            .....                   
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
</ScrollContainer>
```